# Kubernetes node ignoring regular pod creation

Tags: kubernetes

Given a working Kubernetes cluster consisting of a master and some workers.

We need to add a node to run a very specific pod and be part of the cluster for networking reasons. Then being largely ignored for later pod creation by the master.

Adding selectors to every deployment to avoid this node is out of question.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can choose from  [nodeSelector](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/configuration/assign-pod-node/#affinity-and-anti-affinity) or [node affinity](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/configuration/assign-pod-node/#node-affinity).

> `nodeSelector`  provides a very simple way to constrain pods to nodes with particular labels. The affinity/anti-affinity feature, greatly expands the types of constraints you can express. The key enhancements are
>
> 1. the language is more expressive (not just “AND or exact match”)
> 2. you can indicate that the rule is “soft”/“preference” rather than a hard requirement, so if the scheduler can’t satisfy it, the pod will still be scheduled
> 3. you can constrain against labels on other pods running on the node (or other topological domain), rather than against labels on the node itself, which allows rules about which pods can and cannot be co-located
>
> The affinity feature consists of two types of affinity, “node affinity” and “inter-pod affinity/anti-affinity”. Node affinity is like the existing  `nodeSelector`  (but with the first two benefits listed above), while inter-pod affinity/anti-affinity constrains against pod labels rather than node labels, as described in the third item listed above, in addition to having the first and second properties listed above

In short `node affinity` is similar to `nodeSelector` but it allows you to limit which nodes your pod can be scheduled on, based on labels on the node.

You can also look at [taints and tolerations](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/configuration/taint-and-toleration/)

> You add a taint to a node using  [kubectl taint](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/generated/kubectl/kubectl-commands#taint). For example,
>
> ```
> kubectl taint nodes node1 key=value:NoSchedule
> ```
>
> places a taint on node  `node1`. The taint has key  `key`, value  `value`, and taint effect  `NoSchedule`. This means that no pod will be able to schedule onto  `node1`  unless it has a matching toleration.

There is no point of quoting or rewriting the docs in the answer. I really do recommend you go over those and choose the one that better fits your example.

Comment: Thank you Crou, that's exactly what we were looking for.

Comment: See also this answer on DevOps beta: https://devops.stackexchange.com/questions/10707/how-to-introducejoin-new-worker-node-to-an-existing-k8s-cluster-with-selective#10708